# Java - which number has the most divisors

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate which number between 1-10000 that has the most divisors. I want to print out what number that is, and how many divisors there are. And if there's more than one number that has the most divisors I wan't to print out all of those numbers.

Could anyone help me? I'm new at this so please no advanced code.
Thank you

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int divisors = 0;
    //int nr = 10000;

    for (int n = 1; n <= 10000; n++) {



    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        if (n%i==0) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            divisors++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nDivisors: " + divisors);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to show some effort. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've tried putting these numbers into arrayers, but the thing is I actually have no clue what to do. I would provide you with code if I had a proper code, but unfortunately I dont. My code makes no sense right now.

Comment: I just love how people come here and -rep me without even telling me why. Is it because I didn't provide you with code or didn't I explain good enough?

Comment: I think it's because you haven't shown your code. I think you have to paste your code into the question even if it makes no sense.

Comment: I think you get -rep because you show lack of investigation by yourself. A quick google search shows up how to determine the divisors of a number. From there on what are the difficulties you're facing?

Comment: What is the specific problem you're facing?

Comment: The problem is not finding the divisors of a number. I want to find a specific number with the MOST divisors.

Comment: Since people are obviously -repping me because I don't post my nonsense code that is broken at the moment, check the edit on the first post
@Thevenin Mind sending the link then instead of bragging about your searching skills? I've tried google it but apparently you can find it in 5 seconds. thank you.

Comment: @StephanRogers Try starting low. Try programming a program that gets you all divisors of **one** specific number. You already know how to determine if a number is a divisor or not. Now expand it so, that you cound how many divisors for that one number you found. Once youre that far expand your program again so that you can check the number of divisors for a range of values. Often the problem is not the solution itself but the way to big scope a beginner aims for. + edit: your code is not nonsense just because it may be faulty or incomplete!

Answer (score 2):

You're making typical beginner mistakes. You've been given an assignment to program a program that produces output XY and now you struggle to get there because the target you aim for is way out of your scope (yet!).

The thing you should take along while solving this assignment is called algorithmics. Essentially this is the way to deconstruct larger problems into smaller ones that are really easy to be solved by themselves.

So you wan't to go through all numbers from 1 to 10000 and find the ones that have the most divisors.

So what is the smallest possible problem you can solve to get some inches/meters nearer to your wanted solution?

Maybe it would be a program that checks, for two given numbers `a` and `b` if `b` is a divisor of `a`. You already have some code that does exactly this.

So what is the next step?

What about with getting all the the divisors of **one** number. Print them out, look if your program works correctly and somehow save how many divisors this specific number has and also print this value.

Now you already have a taken a good step towards your final goal. You have a program that gets a number and gives you every valid divisor this number has.

From here on you could take different ways to your goal (I'll just show one). As you already determine **how many** divisors a number has, you can now run this program for every number from 1 to 10000 and determine the amount of divisors of each number. If you save them properly you also directly can use this to reach the goal with a last tiny hop.

While iterating through all this 1...10000 numbers you already can save the highest amount of divisors you encountered. So the last step would be to go through your list of **amount of divisors** and print the numbers that have the amount you've already managed to remember as the highest amount you've ever encountered.

You now solved your initial assignment and hopefully learned somehow that you have to break big problems down into smaller ones to make them solvable. So everytime you think "How the hell should I solve this thing? This is too complex for me!" think of "Algorithmics is the solution!" and "I have to break this down into smaller bits". I know it is hard to learn as I tutored many many beginner courses for programming and without exception everyone had this problem, but in the end everyone gets it sooner or later, given he/she tries and tries and tries.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I've managed to count the divisors of the number 10 000 and print them out. As i'm trying to move forward now I can't find a way for the program to run for every number from 1 to 10 000, could you give me a hint? I updated the main post with my newest code.

Comment: Do you know how to write methods? If __yes__ then put your program that determines the divisors for one number into one and just call this method in a loop (counting from 1 to 10000). You would have to think about the parameters and the return of your method but this wouldn't be a big change to your existing program. If __not__ then you should use a(nother) loop to loop through the numbers 1 to 10000 and use the loop counter of this loop to work as an input for your "find all divisors" algorithm you already have.